# Standardized returning values - is it a good or bad idea

Tags: php

I'm working in PHP (but in this case I think the programming language doesn't matter), and in my class methods I usually meet the following situations:

1. Method has to return *true* or *false*
2. Method has to return *true* or *error message*
3. Method has to return *true* + *success message* or *false* + *error message*
4. Method has to return *true* + *success results (object, array, whatever)* or *false*
5. Method has to return *true* + *success results (object, array, whatever)* or *false* + *error message*
6. etc.

My problem is, that when I use this class methods in my code somewhere I always have to come back to the class, and check what is the method actually returning: simply *true* or *false*, *true* or *error message*, etc.

Is a good idea to standardize the returning values? If yes, how?

My idea is:

1. if function has to return *true* or *false* then simply return *true* or *false*
2. if function has to return *true* or *error message* then:

   ```
   if (success)
   {
       return array(
           TRUE,
           null
       );
   }
   else
   {
       return array(
           FALSE,
           $error_message
       );      
   }
   ```
3. if function has to return *true* + *success message* or *error message* then:

   ```
   if (success)
   {
       return array(
           TRUE,
           $success_message,
       );
   }
   else
   {
       return array(
           FALSE,
           $error_message
       );      
   }
   ```
4. etc.

I hope you understand guys my *problem*, even thought my explanation wasn't so good :)
What are your suggestions, or best practices? How should I handle this?

UPDATE:
Let's take a simple example:

```
function login($username, $password) 
{
    // Login logic here ..
    if ($logged_in) 
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    {
        return $error_message;
    }
}
```

So the correct way to do this will be: return *true*, or *throw exception*, and when calling the login method do in withing a *try catch*. So, when somethong goes wrong (validation fails, etc) I should use exceptions.

Comment: This question isn't really a good fit for this site and may be closed.  Please check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information on what kinds of questions to ask here. Stackoverflow isn't really about opinion or suggestions.

Comment: I'm looking for a 'best practice',that is efficient in this situations. I need a 'pattern' to use..this is a problem and I'm looking for a solution. I don't need opinions. I need an efficient solution. I think also others meet similar efficiency problems, and a good solution can help them too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the premise of returning a boolean *and* something else is misguided.

A function should have a clear purpose with a clear result. If this result can be achieved, the result is returned. If the result cannot be achieved, the function either returns `false` or throws an exception. Which is better depends on the situation and your general error-handling philosophy. Either way, it's not typically useful to have a function return an error *message*. That message is not useful to the code that called the function.

PHP has its own mechanism to output error messages in addition to returning `false` results: `trigger_error`. It's purely a tool to aid debugging though, it doesn't replace the standard return value. It can be a good fit for cases where you want to display error messages purely to aid the developer though.

If a function is complex enough to possibly result in several different types of errors that need to be handled differently, you should use exceptions to do so.

For example, a very simple function with a clear purpose that only needs to return `true` or `false`:

```
function isUserLoggedIn() {
    return $this->user == 'logged in';
}
```

A function with a purpose that *may* fail to fulfill that purpose:

```
function convertToFoo($bar) {
    if (!is_int($bar)) {
        return false;
    }
    // here be dragons
    return $foo;
}
```

The same function that also triggers a message, useful for debugging:

```
function convertToFoo($bar) {
    if (!is_int($bar)) {
        trigger_error('$bar must be an int', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // here be dragons
    return $foo;
}
```

A function that may legitimately run into several different kinds of errors that the calling code needs to know about:

```
function httpRequest($url) {
    ...

    if (/* could not connect */) {
        throw new CouldNotConnectException('Response code: ' . $code);
    }

    ...

    if (/* 404 */) {
        throw new PageNotFoundException('Page not found for ' . $url);
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

And I'll paste this comment here as well:

> It should not be the responsibility of the function to prepare, return
>   or display an end-user error message. If the purpose of the function
>   is to, say, fetch something from the database, then displaying error
>   messages is none of its business. The code that called the
>   fetch-from-database function merely needs to be informed of the
>   result; from here there needs to be code whose sole job it is to
>   display an error message in case the database function cannot get the
>   required information. Don't mix those two responsibilities.

Comment: I like the examples you have given here. I would be interested to see an example where you return multiple errors, like when validating a form, there might be 3 or 4 fields that are required that are not filled in, an exception wouldn't really work in that case?

Comment: If validations fails, an exceptions can be thrown containing 'field'-'error message' pairs. This how ORM validation works in Kohana for example.

Comment: @bumper That wouldn't be the responsibility of a single function. There should be one (or several) functions that try to save the data (or whether else you're doing with it), some other code that sets error messages where those functions are not successful, some code that decides whether the thing as a whole was successful or not and some code that displays the error messages if it was not. Cramming all these responsibilities into a single function and expecting it to `return` one thing is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In specific cases, your solutions to return arrays with more than one element which is NOT a collection of entities of the same kind may be an acceptable solution. But in general it's a code smell.

Some problems such a design can hint at:

- You are not using exception handling properly
- Your design goes against the single responsibility principle
- You're always waiting with the return until the end of the method

If a method really fails to do what it is supposed to do, it should not return anything, it should throw an exception.

If your method does more than exactly one task, you have to refactor.

Return as early as possible. Write methods more like this:

```
if (!$something)
{
    return FALSE;
}

//do some other stuff
return 'great, it worked';
```

Your specific login function should not return a message. Such action specific user messages should be decoupled and handled by a message queue.

So you could have a Messenger class which is injected into your controller so you can use it anywhere and add messages to the queue.

```
function login($username, $password) 
{
    // Login logic here ..
    if ($logged_in) 
    {
        $this->messenger->addMessage('success', 'You are loggend in.');
        return TRUE;
    }
    {
        $this->messenger->addMessage('error', $message);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A common idiom from some other languages (*off hand, C#*) is the Do/TryDo method pairing.

```
/**
 * @param  MyInput $input
 * @return MyOutput
 * @throws MyException
 */
function myOperation(MyInput $input) 
{

}
```

`myOperation` *must* throw an exception (*`MyException` in this case*) indicating the failure of the operation. On success, the resulting value (*`MyOutput` in this case*) is returned.

```
/**
 * @param  MyInput  $input
 * @param  MyOutput $output
 * @return bool
 */
function tryMyOperation(MyInput $input, &$output = null) 
{

}
```

`tryMyOperation` *must* return a boolean value indicating the failure *or* success of the operation. It *must not* throw an exception (*directly related to the success or failure of the operation*). The value is assigned to the argument (*`$output` in this case*) passed by reference. Often, the `try*` method can proxy the non-`try*` method.

A contrived example:

```
/**
 * @param  string $input
 * @return string
 * @throws TypeException
 */
function stringToUpper($input) 
{
    if (!is_string($input)) 
    {
        throw new TypeException('String expected');
    }
    return strtoupper($input);
}

/**
 * @param  string $input
 * @param  string $output
 * @return boolean
 */
function tryStringToUpper($input, &$output) 
{
    try 
    {
        $output = stringToUpper($input);
        return true;
    } 
    catch (TypeException $exception) 
    {
        $output = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And would be used as:

```
try 
{
    $output = stringToUpper($input);
    // use $output
} 
catch (TypeException $exception) 
{
    // recover
}

if (tryStringToUpper($input, &$output)) 
{
    // use $output
} 
else 
{
    // recover
}
```

By following a convention like this, the semantics and intent of your code become clearer. If you want to capture the error information, use `myOperation()`, and `catch` the error information. If you're not concerned so much with *why* something broke, rather than *if* something broke, use `tryMyOperation()`.

Comment: +Tomato for using `try{...} catch (...) {...}`

Comment: @crypticツ lol, the alternative being? `try { } ehh maybe_later;`

Comment: Or better, `try { } miss { /* cleanup in aisle 3 */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Error message has nothing to do with return value. **[Antipatterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)** may help to avoid known coding mistakes. Function should return value consistent to its purpose, i.e.:

```
canWriteFile() { return true or false }
writeFile() { should return void }
```

`writeFile()` according to the name the programmer doesn't expect any value and he must study documentation, which cost time, is not intuitive and may lead to mistakes. Invent such names that no documentation is necessary.

You definitely shouldn't use arrays with first item bool, second item error message - this return complex data type instead of simple intuitive value, you will end in writing adapters for common functions and your code soon goes bad.

There are 3 possibilities how to handle errors:

**1) Error flag / state** useful for notices

```
$error = "";
function foo() {
  if($somethingBad) $error = "error occured";
  return !$somethingBad;
}
```

**2) Error handlers** useful for most errors

```
function handleError($message) {
  ...
}

function foo() {
  if($somethingBad) handleError("error occured");
  return !$somethingBad;
}
```

**3) Error catching** useful for errors that can not be handled (i.e. server goes offline during request)

```
function foo() {
  try {
    // dangerous code here
  }
  catch($e) {
    // handle error here
  }
  return !$somethingBad
}
```

Comment: Despite the availability, I wouldn't recommend 1 or 2. **1**, because of global state. **2**, because **3** is better.

Comment: @Bracketworks: from human perspective, yes. But **3** is much slower in most cases.

Comment: Slow or not, I don't think many people would consider it an advisable practice to bolt on a home-brew implementation of a already natively supported language construct.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Exceptions**

I would suggest diving into Exceptions a bit, as they can come in handy. First, you get rid of returning error messages: You throw an exception instead.

Second, you need no true or false return code anymore: If everythings works as expected, you know this because no exception is thrown.

If you handle success and error messages within your classes, you might also want to get rid of them. Such things should get handled in a very frontend-near class which checks for exceptions and then sets a error message depending on the exception or a success message.

**Reusable Classes**

Methods should return objects the application can work with. The moment you start using return values as messages which get passed through the system, you are depending on this messages to be there which makes it hard to replace the underlying class.

A good way of thinking is the following: Can I use my class in another project? If you have custom error messages in there, it may be hard as you may need others in another project and have to change your class. So you want to handle only a global success or error (by exception) and then add the custom error messages near your frontend.

Answer (score -1):

A *standard* way is apparently this one: **return result or false.**
On error throw an exception.

Comment: To return mixed values means to test type after each call: this is bad habit from PHP, definitely not standard.

Comment: Yea, its unfortunate that this is the standard way of doing things in PHP; it's consistent (*some of the time*) so that's worth something, but it sorta stinks.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what your app is doing. In one case, I had to design a big REST API based app, and I wanted errors to be able to bubble up and be verbose to any part of the API, up to the user level. so what I did was that:

1. Each function returns an error/success code, that should be meaningful.
2. OK is 1, and "General Failure" is 0, so it's boolean compliant.
3. specialized error codes are values less than 0.
4. you have a class that enumerates all values, so you don't have to remember codes.
5. this class also has textual representation of the errors for display and logging.
6. this class also has 2 methods `OK($errorCode)` and `FAIL($errorCode)`, to use inside `if`s

the class looks something like

```
class Error {

    const OK = 1;
    //general error
    const FAIL = 0;
    //invalid url
    const RequestParseError = -1;
    //resource not found
    const ResourceNotFound = -2;

    ....

    static public function _($errCode) {

        switch ($errCode) {

            case Error::OK:
                return "OK";

            case Error::FAIL:
                return "General Failure";

            case Error::RequestParseError:
                return "Request Parse Error";

        .....
    }

}
```

that way, each level of the app can return an error code, and it will bubble upwards as much as you want. and the OK() and FAIL() functions are compatible with boolean returning functions.

Comment: So you're replicating PHP's Exception Handling?

Comment: I hate exceptions, what can I say.

Comment: let me elaborate a bit more: if most oh PHP's library functions  don't raise exceptions, doing this with exceptions means translating one convention to another all the time, which is annoying. in python, where everything raises exceptions, it is much simpler and embedded in the language philosophy.

Comment: Well, fair enough, but [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) + [ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) = significantly better than native errors or home-brew exceptions. Moreover, isn't `Error::OK` semantically equivalent to ... well, no error?